# Standard Form of Linear Program

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, linear-programming

I have this problem:
Consider the linear program :
 $$ \text{ minimize }  z =c^{T}x $$
 $$ \text{ subject to }  Ax = b$$
$$ \text{}x \geq0$$
Transform it into an equivalent standard-form problem for which the right-hand-side vector is zero .

**Hint:** You can achieve this by introducing an additional variable and an additional constraint.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. On the other hand, I believe the typical "standard form" only requires $b\ge0$.

Comment: This problem appears in the book "Linear and Nonlinear Optimization" of Griva,Nash and Sofer ; Chapter 4 pag 106.

Comment: Which standard form do you have?

Comment: I think we can assume that the program is in its standard form

Comment: I add the hint to your question, which is given in the book.